# Is there a way I can detect text from an Image using Expo React Native?

Tags: react-native, camera, tesseract, expo

I am working with `Expo`, `React Native` and I want to to be able to detect text from images. Is there an package i can work with to achieve this?

I am using `Expo camera module` to snap the picture and supply the URI to the text detector
I have tried using react-native-text-detector but I am getting the error that the function detectFromUri is not defined. I have also tried with tesserect.js but it fails on import with "unable to resolve variable location".

```js
await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options).then(photo => {
       photo.exif.Orientation = 1;
                //console.log(photo.uri);
        const visionResp = await RNTextDetector.detectFromUri(photo.uri);
        if (!(visionResp && visionResp.length > 0)) {
            throw "UNMATCHED";
        }
        console.log(visionResp);
});
```

I am expecting the visionResp to log the results returned from the detection but instead i get `undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeTextDetector.default.detectFromUri')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is your project created with `expo-cli`?

If yes, Expo is not supporting OCR currently. There is a feature request on [canny.io](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/support-optical-character-recognition-ocr) but you can't know for sure when it will become available.
Your only choice is to use an OCR service like [this one](https://ocr.space/ocrapi).Internet connectivity will be required.

If not, (and the project is created with `react-native-cli`) you should be able to successfully use `react-native-text-detector`. Just make sure you link the package correctly. Docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-text-detector)

Comment: I created it using create-react-native-app

Comment: That project is no longer maintained - `expo-cli` took its place. This means you are bound to Expo and you won't be able to use use react-native-text-decorator unless you eject.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are not forced to use expo and you didn't put too much work into the project, you can try creating a new project with `react-native-cli`. Keep in mind you'll need XCode/Android studio to build the app.